# couldn't send retry but the message has been sent

Tags: botframework

In the bot web chat, when I type a message, the bot says "sending" first and then changes to "couldn't send, Retry".  But the message is sent and I am getting the reply.  How can I avoid this?  Do I need to increase the message timeout?  If so, where I need to set it?

[image]

This is the code snippet.  I am using C# SDK where I have coded in MessageReceivedASync method

```
namespace Bot_Application1.Dialogs
{
    public class HRBotDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public static string dialogcontext = "";
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            // Get the text passed
            var message = await argument;
            string typedText = message.Text.ToLower();
            string answer = "My Answer";
            if ((typedText == "hi") || (typedText == "hello"))
            {
                answer = message.Text;

            }
            else if ((typedText == "how many personal days do i have left") || (typedText.Contains("personal days")))
            {
                answer = "Looks like you have 2 remaining for this year";
            }
```

I am adding the controller code here

```
//[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new HRBotDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            var reply = HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            if (reply != null)
                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {

        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            string replyMessage = string.Empty;
            if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
            {
                replyMessage += $"How can I help you? \n";
                return message.CreateReply(replyMessage);
            }
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this consistent? How did you create the bot? (Bot Service, Node or C# sdk)?

Comment: Could you add the code from the "Post"-method in your MessagesController.

Comment: I've seen this issue when sending a null reply.  As suggested by Xeno-D, please provide the code in the messages controller.

Comment: Hi I have added the controller code.  Except for ConversationUpdate messages, all other code is automatic.

Comment: Hey i am facing exactly same issue and i was wondering if anybody had any suggestion?

Comment: Same here. Anyone found the fix for this? Looks like this is happening when the ResumeAfter method is taking more time to complete execution,

Comment: @narasimman Did you find fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the Serializable attribute to your HRBotDialog like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class HRBotDialog : IDialog<object>
{
//...code...
}
```

Comment: Even if that attribute is added to the class, I am still facing the same issue. When the Dialog that is being called in the ResumeAfter method is taking some to execute, I am seeing this error in the emulator. Is there any way to tell the framework that the message is received by the code properly?